# JDBCTemplate is null

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am attempting to connect to a database using JDBC template and have a application.config file with the following:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/herosighting<br>
spring.datasource.username=root<br>
spring.datasource.password=<br>
```

I do know that this `application.properties` is being read as I tried changing the `server.port` and it did work.

Now I have the following code:

```
@Repository
public class LocationDaoImpl implements LocationDao 
{
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbc;

@Override
public Location addLocation(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void updateLocation(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public List<Location> getAllLocations() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void deleteLocationById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public List<Location> heroLocationsById(int heroId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Location> sightingsOnDate(Date date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Location getLocationById(int id) 
{
     final String SELECT_ROOM_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE id = ?";
     return jdbc.queryForObject(SELECT_ROOM_BY_ID, new LocationMapper(), id);//returns room Object
}
}
```

The return in the last method is returning null becuase the JDBCTemplate is null.

I called the method in main to test it like so:

```
@Repository
public class Test {
@Autowired
static LocationDao dao;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Location l = dao.getLocationById(1);

}

}
```

The interesting thing is, to my knowledge I had the exact same configuration in another file with exact same pom.xml and that project the jdbc worked

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sg</groupId>
    <artifactId>SuperheroSightings</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SuperheroSightings</name>
    <description>Full stack Spring application for Superhero Sightings</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT:As there was confusion with my question, I do have a main where i intalize the spring application and this works fine:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class SuperheroSightingsApplication 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
    SpringApplication.run(SuperheroSightingsApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

I am not trying to run unit tests or anything. All I am trying to do is run a method from my DAO to see if the connection to the database is working. The issue is the JDBCTemplate is null and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the exact error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sg.SuperheroSightings.Dao.LocationDao.getLocationById(int)" because "com.sg.SuperheroSightings.Test.dao" is null
at com.sg.SuperheroSightings.Test.main(Test.java:18)

Comment: You should look into how to create decent tests. There is no reason to mark Test as a Repository, there's also no reason to have a main method in there.

Comment: 1. you cannot inject into `static` fields. 2. you are running the main without using spring no injection will ever take place.

Comment: If you want to test your application, you should have a look at the @SpringBootTest Annotation

Comment: "The return in the last method is returning null becuase the JDBCTemplate is null": not possible. It would *throw* a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how a main method from a Spring Boot Application should look like.
It should be something like this to startup correctly:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
 }
```

Comment: he is trying to test his repository, it's not meant as a spring boot application

Comment: @Stultuske there is no hint that he tries to test. To me he just tries to play with the spring context to see if he can connect to the database

Comment: @Boug the OP stated in the question: 'to test it'.

Comment: @Andreas Radauer I have updated my question. I think there was some confusion as I do have that exact code in my project and it runs fine, this is a separate file.